# Why do appearance methods get called even when the view controller is not explicitly added as a child?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

While researching container view controllers in an attempt to refactor some code, I came upon something that I do not understand.

The Apple documentation tells me that in order for child view controllers to get their appearance methods called they must be added as children to a parent view controller using `addChildViewController:`

This puzzles me as my code does not use any of the container view controller methods and yet all of my child view controllers are getting the `viewWillAppear:` message.

I've boiled the code down to this simple example, where you will see "ChildViewController:viewWillAppear:" in the debug log despite any calls to `addChildViewController:`

```
@interface ChildViewController : UIViewController
@end

@implementation ChildViewController

- (void)loadView {
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 250.0f, 250.0f)];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"ChildViewController:viewWillAppear:");
}

@end


@interface RootViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong) ChildViewController *cvc;
@end

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize cvc;
- (void)loadView {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 500.0f, 500.0f)];
    cvc = [[ChildViewController alloc] init];
    [view addSubview:[cvc view]];
    self.view = view;
}

@end


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Why does this work?

Comment: Could you link to which Apple document says that? Maybe I'm just dense but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process of calling `addSubview` is what will result in the view appearing and thus resulting in the `loadView`,  `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidAppear`, etc., calls. The `addChildViewController` (and the call to `didMoveToParentViewController` that you should also do) does not affect this.

You call `addChildViewController` to make sure your controller hierarchy stays in sync with the view hierarchy. If you don't do this, you won't get certain events getting passed to your child controller (such as rotation events). Also, by doing `addChildViewController`, your controller will be retained for you, without you needing to maintain your own property to keep track of the child controllers.

If you see [WWDC 2011 - #201 Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102), it will talk about the importance of keeping the view hierarchy and the controller hierarchy synchronized.